# Pull value from PHP Cookie Array

Tags: php, cookies

I am doing some modifications for a site built primarily in ASP.  However, the mods will be in PHP as the site is being moved over to that language.

When the user signs in, they are assigned cookies that look lkie so:

```
("mycook")("id")=23
("mycook")("pref")="HTML"
("mycook")("job")="janitor"
```

Now in asp, these can be referenced as:

```
request.cookies("mycook")("pref")
```

which would respond as "HTML"

Is there a similar syntax is PHP that anyone is aware of?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
echo $_COOKIE['mycook']['pref'];
echo $_COOKIE["mycook"]["pref"];
```

I saw a solution that uses a For Each -> , and I can see how that would work.  But it just seems a bit of overkill (to loop through all the values just to print the one I am looking for) and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I you use var_dump($_COOKIE); you'll be able to see what's in that variable -- and see the structure of your cookies. Try using that, and edit your question with that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your cookies will be stored as the following string in the "mycook" cookie:

```
["mycook"]=>string(27) "pref=HTML&job=janitor&id=23"
```

So to access you will need `echo $_COOKIE['mycook']` then [translate the url encoded string into something more useful](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str($_COOKIE['mycook'], $mycook);
echo $mycook['pref'];
```

If you don't need to have second level cookies, just assigning as:

```
Response.Cookies("id")=23
Response.Cookies("pref")="HTML"
Response.Cookies("job")="janitor"
```

Will allow you to access the cookies in PHP with just:

```
echo $_COOKIE['pref'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I would love if they didn't use second level cookies, but they do, and they are throughout the site.  Thanks for your help with parse_str, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

here is a few link that will help:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php