# Converting ASP multidimensional cookie into PHP

Tags: php, cookies, asp-classic, multidimensional-array

I'm converting a site from classic ASP into PHP and have come across a piece of functionality that I may have problems with.

The ASP appears to use multidimensional cookies:

```
basket_id = request.cookies(cookie_order_prefix)(cookie_basket_number)
```

With php not supporting multidimensional cookies. Is there a way I can handle this?

Many thanks

Comment: use `serialize()` (or maybe `json_encode()`) to embed a string-ified native PHP array in the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP just turns the cookie into a URL encoded string.

Taken from a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6775993/443316), which has an explanation of what's going on:

```
parse_str($_COOKIE['firstlevel'], $mycook);
echo $mycook['secondlevel'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in javascript [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060598/write-asp-style-cookie-with-keys-using-javascript-read-using-classic-asp/14060971#14060971)

The concept should be the same and get you through.